# How to use spread as parameters in function?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have tried this case:

```
let a = { id: 1, name: "Misha" };


function b(id: number, name: string) {

}

b(...a);
```

I need that all properties of object will be applied as parameters

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TypeScript doesn't support spreading objects to parameter names.

If it's possible for you to change the function signature though, you can expect an object of a compatible type as the first function parameter, like this:

```js
// interface name is just an example
interface IUser {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

let a: IUser = { id: 1, name: "Misha" };

function b({ id, name }: IUser) {
  console.log(`User ID is ${id} and name is "${name}"`);
}

b(a);
```

Comment: In this case why we use ...a instead a?

Comment: Straight no answer is very useful too. It stops the search and saves time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

like this.

```
function NewFunction(...[foo, bar]: Parameters<typeof OtherFunction>){}
function OtherFunction(enabled?: boolean; message?: string) {}
```

Answer (score -3):

[TypeScript does support spreading objects to parameter names.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html)

Write the three dots before the parameter name, and an array operator next to the type.

Example :

```
function add(x: number, ...vals: number[])
```

Comment: This is for arrays only, not objects with named properties (or object literals)